# x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc linker error

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, linker, cygwin

I setup in my cygwin environment the x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc package to get a recent gcc

```
$ x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc --version
x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
```

I have a small code file that you can find [here](http://pastebin.com/N9g8YG9t)
to build i use the following line:

```
 x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 TreasureHunter.cpp
```

Compilation is OK, but I get several link error about std::istream see below. What is the issue does it means I missed a package during the setup ?

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x60): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x7c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0xc2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x11e): relocation
truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x2d2): relocation
truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o:TreasureHunter.cpp:(.text+0x2ed): relocation
truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/abuisson/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9qeGVh.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata$_ZSt4__lgl'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're compiling C++ code with `gcc` rather than `g++` you will need to at least add `-lstdc++` to your command line. Better to just use `g++` in the first place though.